# How to use terraform outputs as variables in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to pass the databricks workspace name that is generated from the terraform deployment with Azure DevOps to another step as a variable but not sure how to do.

So I defined the output in my output.tf

```
output "workspace_name" {
  value = azurerm_databricks_workspace.databricks.name
}
```

and I can see the output :

[image]

and going through stackoverflow, there is a solution to make all of your outputs as variables  automatically:

1- 
configure output variable:

[image]

2- configure powershell script to get them and populate it

[image: powershell]

3- now what ? what will the variable name be, and how can I use it in the Databricks Bearer Token solution ?

Comment: do you not understand the code you are using? the name would be `workspace_name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}
```

The logic of this script is used to loop through the `output` json file that your previous terraform generated.

And this line `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)"` aim to setting the `name` which showed in the `output` json file as the pipeline variable name, also set its corresponding value from output json file to the value of its pipeline variable.

Here is their mapping show:

```
Terraform Output Json                          Azure devops pipeline 

   Output name            ================>      varaible name

   Output value           ================>      variable value
```

---

So, in Databricks Bearer Token task, you can directly call the variable via its name you configured in `terraform` file: `workspace_name`.

Comment: @Renm Welcome:-) So is it succeed for you to call variable now?

Comment: I understood the concept but I still have a small problem, It's not finding the json file:

Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\a\r1\a\TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath' because it does not exist.

So the jsonPath is not correct somehow ?, unfortunately the documentation is not descriptive

Comment: `Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\a\r1\a\TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath' because it does not exist.`

`At D:\a\_temp\767f0155-b40f-4275-978e-fdc72ccdedbf.ps1:6 char:9
$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\a\r1\a\Terra...utVariablesPath:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
`

Comment: @Renm did you specify the terraformoutput.jsonxxx as output variable in your terraform task, and then pass it to jsonPath in powershell task? Please use write-host in powershell to print the Terraformoupt.jsonoutputvariablepath value.

Comment: Yes, I did specificy the TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath in the apply command of the terraform (same as the pictures in the question) and passed it to the powershell.

This is my script



`write-host $TerraformOutput.jsonPlanFilePath
write-host $jsonPath
get-variable

$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json


foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}`



and both jsonPath and TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath variables don't exist

Comment: @Renm It seems you missed the () when calling variable. What about try with $(variable name)?

Comment: This is the script now: 
`write-host $(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath)

$json = Get-Content $env:jsonPath | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json


foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}`

and the value is:
-------
 `D:\a\r1\a\output-fc58ce30-e2g8-4399-8389-ad2f5c176bee.json`
--------
erroe message:
`Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\a\r1\a\TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath' because it does not exist.`
--------
`At D:\a\_temp\827a8331-aa75-405e-866b-b1c32fa0c1ba.ps1:4 char:9`

Comment: @Renm Just off my work office and is using phone to give reply. Would you mind I give you exact cause after I back to office and have a complete try tomorrow?

Comment: @Renm Or for personal troubleshooting, you can change agent to self-agent. When using self agent, you can check files from local. Then you could see whether it is cause the file does not generate, or because of variable configured.

Comment: I don't mind at all !, thanks for helping i'm in your debt :), i'll check the self-agent

Comment: This has worked:

`$json = Get-Content $(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json


foreach($prop in $json.psobject.properties) {
    Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($prop.Name);]$($prop.Value.value)")
}
`

Changing   $env:jsonPath to  $(TerraformOutput.jsonOutputVariablesPath) fixed the problem

thanks again for your help @Merlin Liang - MSFT :)

Comment: @Renm Awesome you find the right way!! and welcome

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that you're using Azure Devops to create Databricks Bearer token, which can be simplified by using [Databricks Labs Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#special-configurations-for-azure) provider, which supports AAD tokens.